# How to let a socket server accept only once

Tags: c, linux

I have a really big headache.

If there is a case that I have many socket client and only one socket server, how can I make the server only accept the first connect() order he received, and fail all the other connect() from other client? I'm using C in linux btw

I'm really struggle with this question. In other words, how can I make a client recognizance that "**Hey,this port number of this ip is busy, I need to try another one maybe.**"

My teacher told me that I will get a **timeout error** if i just let a client connect to a server, while another client has connect to the same ip same port recently. But, well, I just cannot find where is the error. **Both of the connect() functions in two clients return 0.**

Maybe I misunderstand my teacher's word,but since the program doesn't crash and no negative number returned from functions, where is it,how can I find it?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Er, only call `accept()` once and then close the listening socket after it succeeds?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a value of 0 or 1 for backlog in your `listen()` call.

I haven't tried it, but the man page claims that extra connections will get a `ECONNREFUSED` error.

Immediately after calling `accept` to get your actual socket to the first client close the listener. Otherwise another client can queue up.